# JavaMail Gmail SMTP ошибка авторизации

Tags: java

Пытаюсь отправить *email* при помощи *JavaMail API*, но постоянно выдает ошибку:

> AuthenticationException

Логин и пароль от *Gmail* верный.

Нужно ли настраивать *Gmail SMTP*, и если да, то как это сделать?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("mymail@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В гугловом аккаунте надо разрешить вход с "небезопасных" приложений - иначе он только через oauth пускает

Comment: Это через Admin консоль нужно настраивать ?